# Is there a way to define functions in a dictionary directly?

Tags: python, dictionary, object

I have a game, written in python, and I want there to be one, all-controlling dictionary, with all the values and functions to run the game. The only thing is, I don't want to define the functions, then put them into the function. I was thinking of something like this:

```
Dictionary = {
    function1 : def():
        stuff,
    function2 : def():
        stuff
}
```

There is a way to do this in Javascript Objects like this:

```
var Object = {
    function1 : function() {},
    function2 : function() {}
}
```

Is there any way to do that in Python?

Comment: maybe just use a class instead of a dictionary?

Comment: "I don't want to define the functions, then put them into the dictionary" - why not?

Comment: I wanted to use a class, but a class can't be saved in Pickle

Comment: `pickle` can save ***instances*** of classes. Regardless, there's a third-party module called `dill` that can pickle classes.

Comment: "and I want there to be one, all-controlling dictionary, with all the values and functions to run the game." That doesn't make any sense. You shouldn't use a dictionary for that. Anyway, you can use a lambda expression, but that will be very limiting for what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can assign function objects (i.e. also lambdas) as values to a dictionary. Not a very useful, but an example. You have `function1` assigned to key `"function1"` of `dict` `d` and a lambda to key `"function2"` and both are then called:

```
def function1():
    print("function1")

d = {
    "function1": function1,
    "function2": lambda: print("function2")
}

d["function1"]()
d["function2"]()
```

Comment: Thank you, though I don't think python dictionaries are build like javascript objects, so there is no right answer.